# AttributeError: 'InstanceState' object has no attribute '_post_inspect' when querying user details during login

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a login route in my application where users submit their credentials. As part of the login process, I'm querying the user details from the database to check if the user exists in the system. However, when running the code on Ubuntu, I encounter the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'InstanceState' object has no attribute '_post_inspect'
```

Interestingly, the code runs without any issues on a Windows machine.
Here is the sample my code

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""
    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        username = request.form.get("username")
        password_entered = request.form.get("password")
      

        if username == "":
            return "Username missing", 403
        elif password_entered == "":
            return "Password missing", 403

        # Query database for username
        user = session_db.query(User).filter(User.username == username) .first()

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if user is None or not user.verify_password(password_entered):
            return "Invalid username or password", 403

        print("User ID:", user.id)
        # Remember which user has logged in
        print(session)
        session["user_id"] = user.id
        print("Session user_id:", session["user_id"])
        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("page_login.html")
```

```
# Define the user model
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(64) ,index=True, unique=True)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    password_hash = Column(String(64))
    cash = Column(Float, default=10000.00)
    time_stamp = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

# database connection
def dbconnect():
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///finance.db", connect_args={'check_same_thread': False})
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    db_session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    return db_session()
```

I'm using SQLAlchemy to interact with the database. The User model has been defined, and the connection to the database seems to be working fine. However, when executing the line          **user = session_db.query(User).filter(User.username == username) .first()**
, I encounter the AttributeError mentioned above. The strange part is that the code runs successfully on a Windows machine. I have compared the code and configuration between the two environments but couldn't find any significant differences.

I have tried searching for a solution or similar issues, but I haven't found anything specific to this error related to querying with SQLAlchemy.

Could you please help me understand the cause of this error and suggest a solution? Am I missing something in my code or configuration that could be causing this issue on linux Ubuntu?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.